# Percentages a single column's values in separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

For the following dataframe:

```
   person  choice
0  A       1
1  A       2
2  A       1
3  B       3
4  B       3
5  B       2
6  B       1
7  C       2
```

how can I find the percentage of each choice per person?

The output should be something like the following:

```
person  choice_1_count choice_2_count choice_3_count  total
A                    2              1              0      3 
B                    1              1              2      4
C                    0              1              0      1
```

to be used to find percentages:

```
person  choice_1_percent  choice_2_percent  choice_3_percent
A                  66.67             33.33              0.00
B                  25.00             25.00             50.00
C                   0.00            100.00              0.00
```

The format of the final dataframe matters, for example in sorting and plotting the percentage columns, and further analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets use `crosstab` to calculate frequency table and `normalize` across `index` axis to calculate percentages

```
dist = pd.crosstab(df['person'], df['choice'], normalize='index') * 100
```

Result

```
choice          1           2     3
person                             
A       66.666667   33.333333   0.0
B       25.000000   25.000000  50.0
C        0.000000  100.000000   0.0
```

Then you can plot the percentages

```
dist.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.value_counts(['person', 'choice']).sort_index(), columns=["count"])
df["percent"] = df["count"]/df.groupby('person')['count'].transform('sum')
```

Comment: Thanks, that gives the needed numbers, although the format matters, for example, sorting by each column and creating plots of % for each choice.

Comment: To get closer to the required datadframe format, it helps to use: `df.reset_index(inplace=True)`